# Map List < Object > to List < ObjectSrv >

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, modelmapper

I want to Map List < City > to List < CitySrv >  in the service layer but i dont have any idea how to do that.

the City srv that i want to Map: (srv = server response value)

```
@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
    public class CitySrv {
        private Long id;
        private String name;
        private Long state;
    }
```

the City Entity that want to map From:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@SuperBuilder
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "IOTP_CITY")
public class City extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "state_id")
    private State state;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "city")
    private List<Branch> branches = new ArrayList<Branch>();

}
```

i used Model mapper before but for some reason i cant use it anymore.

```
        @Override
    public GenericResponse<List<CitySrv>> getAllCities() throws ProjectException {
        Optional<List<City>> citiiesSrvResponse = cityRepository.getAllCities();
        if (citiiesSrvResponse.isPresent()) {
            List<CitySrv> citiesList = modelMapper.map(citiiesSrvResponse.get(), new 
                TypeToken<List<CitySrv>>() {
            }.getType());
            return ResponseUtil.getResponse(citiesList);
        } else throw new ProjectException(ExceptionStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
```

Comment: Probably your best option is not asking how to go around your previous code, but instead - understanding why your previously working code is not working anymore. It usually isn't something that just happens, so that must be your doing.

Comment: The Technical lead of my team is not agree with yousing Mappers thats why i post it here @M.Prokhorov

Comment: Is your company willing to pay for you writing equivalent frameworks by hand? Then go for it.

Comment: What you tried ? Simply can't iterate and set values from one to another  ?

Comment: in this case iteration make a bad smell @Prasath

Answer (score 0):

i handle it just like this but its not so good

```
public GenericResponse<List<CitySrv>> getAllCities() throws ProjectException 
    {
    Optional<List<City>> citiiesSrvResponse = cityRepository.getAllCities();
    CitySrv citySrv = new CitySrv();
    List<CitySrv> citySrvList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (citiiesSrvResponse.isPresent()) {
        for (City eachCity : citiiesSrvResponse.get()) {
            citySrv.setId(eachCity.getId());
            citySrv.setName(eachCity.getName());
            citySrv.setState(eachCity.getState().getId());
            citySrvList.add(citySrv);
        }
        return ResponseUtil.getResponse(citySrvList);
    } else throw new ProjectException(ExceptionStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

Comment: it does exactly same thing as mapper would do. What's the problem with that solution?

Comment: Mapper cant handle the Objects for this case Mapper got error when  want to do:
            citySrv.setState(eachCity.getState().getId());
@Morph21

Answer (score 0):

For modelMapper to work your source and destination have to be similar enough. You want to map the entity State in City to a Long which is its id in CitySrv. Which I would guess doesn't fulfill this criteria. You have to tell modelMapper how to map that by configuring a mapping

```
TypeMap<City, CitySrv> propertyMapper = modelMapper.createTypeMap(City.class, CitySrv.class);
propertyMapper.addMappings(
    mapper -> mapper.map(src -> src.getState().getId, CitySrv::setState)
);
```

Best you do that in a global config.
You can find more info in this [baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-modelmapper)